# How to print datetime every 20sec if I didn't get message from client

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, timeout, client-server

I've just created client - server communication via multithreading.
My problem is that I want to display a message after every 20 seconds when no message has been received.

Here's my code:

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , new_socket , c;
    struct sockaddr_in server , address;

    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = 3;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

//  if (setsockopt (socket_desc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
//      perror("setsockopt failed\n");

//  if (setsockopt (socket_desc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
//      perror("setsockopt failed\n");

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( PORT );

    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    puts("Oczekiwanie na połączenia ...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    pthread_t thread_id;

    while( (new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        printf("Połączono z nowym klientem, socket fd: %d , ip: %s , port: %d \n" , new_socket , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));

        if( pthread_create( &thread_id , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) &new_socket) < 0)
        {
            perror("ERROR: nie można utworzyć wątku");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    if (new_socket < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and handler function:

```
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    char *message , client_message[2000];

    message = "Nazwiązano połączenie z serwerem \r\n";
    write(sock , message , strlen(message));

    //przetwarzanie wiadomosci
    while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
        client_message[read_size] = '\0';

        printf("%s", client_message);

        memset(client_message, 0, 2000);
    }

    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        printf("Połączenie z klientem zostało przerwane\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would like get the same result as Select here:

```
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 20;
tv.tv_usec = 0;

activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , &tv);

    if (activity == -1)
       perror("select() failed");
    else if (activity){
        tv.tv_sec = delay;
    }
    else{
        time_t t = time(0);
        cout << "DELAY MESSAGE: " << currentDateTime() << endl;
        tv.tv_sec += delay;
    }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Note that 'pthread_create( &thread_id , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) &new_socket), is dangerous, even though the first thing you do in the client-server thread is dereference it and store the sock locally.  If two clients connect in quick succession, 'new_socket' may be overwritten by a second accept() return before the client-server thread can get at it.

Comment: Set the SO_RCVTIMEO option in the sock received in the client-server thread, (see other comment !!)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set socket option to SO_RCVTIMEO. Refer the following link for more info on this socket option.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/setsockopt

your code in connection_handler should set this option as below

```
struct timeval tv; 
tv.tv_sec = 20;  /* 20 Secs Timeout */

setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,(struct timeval *)&tv,sizeof(struct timeval));

/*Now you should read*/
```

Your read method would unblock after specified time of 20 seconds with errno set to EAGAIN EWOULDBLOCK. You could handle this errno in the loop condition to get the desired functionality.

Comment: Ok it almost works, anyway I still can't cout a msg with time.

Comment: You mean can't cout when recv times out?

Comment: I mean, cant print when that delay is over. So if it checks for messages for 20sec and it didn't get any of them, then put msg to user and loop for messages again. So it's like infinity loop, but if noone use that port for 20sec it tells it with message but still waiting for new messages.

Comment: Could not follow your question fully. When you set the socket with SO_RCVTIMEO option, your read will timeout after every specified time (20s here). When you put this read in infinite loop, you'll check for errno only for timeouts (EAGAINA/EWOULDBLOCK) else break for other error.